# "Sorry, something went wrong. Try your request again. If the problem continues, contact us." when tapping "Submit for Review" iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Submitting version 1 of my app. As soon as I tap on "Submit for Review" getting this error, has anyone else encountered this error? Searching on google for the error doesn't bring up anything interesting.

1. All screenshots/content/requirements are ready.
2. Build is processed, icons are uploaded; all is ready to go!
3. No other indication of error.

Tried logging out and logging in, tried using iTunesConnect on Safari and also on Chrome.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Just curious how long did it take for this error to go away for you? Facing this issue myself today.

Comment: I think we just waited for a bit, like 15 to 30 minutes and it went away.

Comment: Also try to login, logout, clear cookies, go from chrome to safari, things like that. That's what we did and seems to have worked, good luck!

Comment: Check the Apple Developer System Status if something is wrong with Apple Service then you need to wait until that service up and start working. ```https://developer.apple.com/system-status/```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, download the Transporter app from the app store, and upload your .ipa exported from Xcode.